# Office word throw warning info when open officer generated docx with tiff in it

Tags: r, docx, tiff, officer

When I'm opening a docx file generated by `R` package `officer` which is inserted with a tiff picture file, the Office 2016 throw me an error massage.

example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)

img <- "test.tiff"
pic <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
img %>% ggsave(pic, width = 6, height = 3)

read_docx() %>% 
    body_add_img(img, width = 6, height = 3) %>% 
    print(target = "test.docx")
```

Then when opening `test.docx`, I got an error massage

> We're sorry. We can't open test.docx because we found a problem with its contents.
>
> Details
>
> > The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.

After I press 'OK' button, Word ask me if I want to recover the contents of the document. Choose 'yes' then I got a Document1 with correct picture in it.

I tried .jpg and .png format, and they both worked correctly, so this can be a work-around for now. Is this a bug or just me making mistakes? Either way it is truly welcomed to enlighten me, thanks.

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                                   
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] officer_0.2.0 ggplot2_2.2.1 magrittr_1.5 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14      digest_0.6.13     R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R6_2.2.2          grid_3.4.3       
 [6] plyr_1.8.4        gtable_0.2.0      scales_0.5.0      zip_1.0.0         rlang_0.1.6      
[11] uuid_0.1-2        lazyeval_0.2.1    R.oo_1.21.0       R.utils_2.6.0     xml2_1.1.1       
[16] labeling_0.3      tools_3.4.3       munsell_0.4.3     yaml_2.1.16       compiler_3.4.3   
[21] base64enc_0.1-3   colorspace_1.3-2  htmltools_0.3.6   tibble_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

As written [here](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/offcran/graphics.html#r-plots), only png, jpg and emf have been tested. However, support for tiff is quite easy to integrate, I will push un an update to handle that later today on Github.

Comment: you can try the github version now

Comment: Thanks for rapidly response. Great work you are doing by the way, Markdown's driving me crazy.

Comment: thanks. It is 2 different things. I am using rmarkdown on a daily basis. I am using officer to automate *corporate reporting* when it has to be pptx or docx. ++